# What is the default or most commonly used multiprocessing model in Linux? Symmetric or Asymmetric?

Tags: linux, process-management, architecture

What the multiprocessing model for Linux? Is there a default or most commonly used model? Is it similar or very different from say BSD or even the MS Windows kernel?

If SMP is used normally, can assymetric be used instead if desired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_multiprocessing):

> Asymmetric multiprocessing (AMP) was a software stopgap for handling
>   multiple CPUs before symmetric multiprocessing (SMP) was available.

Linux uses SMP.